# Invalid Resource Id Google Calendar API

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apps

I am just trying the google Calendar API explorer and I am sure I have the right calendarId and I am sure the ruleId is my username that has access, but I always get the "Invalid Resource Id", and since I am just playing with the explorer I can't even add my own resource Id as many suggestions.

I posted the explorer below:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/calendar/v3/calendar.acl.get

Answer (score 1):

The id is not just the calendar email (it always contains a prefix of the user kind). Try doing a list of acls first:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/calendar/v3/calendar.acl.list?calendarId=primary&_h=1&